# When I am adding elements in my template string inside a "for" loop, it returns the word "undefined" at the beginning of the string

Tags: javascript

When I am adding elements in my template string inside a "for" loop, it returns the word "undefined" at the beginning of the string.

Despite the fact that I initialize all my object's properties. I am even controlling that all elements are defined.

How can I avoid this "undefined" statement at the beggining of the loop?

Here my javascript's snippet:

```js
let templateString
let objectStock={
  A:"A", 
  B:"B",
  C:"C",
  D:"D",
}


for(let objectItem in objectStock){
  if(
    objectItem === undefined || 
    objectStock === undefined || 
    objectStock[objectItem] === undefined
  ) continue

  templateString+= `<br><p><b>${objectItem}</b>: ${ objectStock[objectItem] || "empty field."}</p>`
}

console.log("templateString: ", templateString)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not problem of your loop.
You didn't specify any value in variable declaration `let templateString` so it's value is `undefined`. It works with `let templateString = '';`.

```js
// Hey JavaScript, it's string!
let templateString = '';
let objectStock={
  A:"A", 
  B:"B",
  C:"C",
  D:"D",
}

for(let objectItem in objectStock){
  templateString+= `<br><p><b>${objectItem}</b>: ${ objectStock[objectItem] || "empty field."}</p>`
}

console.log("templateString: ", templateString)
```